# Why docker-compose doesn't get me into interactive mode

Tags: linux, docker, shell, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to get into interactive mode using docker compose, I have create a Dockerfile just for testing

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

and used this `docker-compose` file which contains the two fields `tty: true` and `stdin_open: true`

#### docker-compose

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-test
    build: .
    image: docker-test
    stdin_open: true 
    tty: true
```

but when I hit the command `sudo docker-compose up` it doens't get into interactive mode, and it's the output

```bash
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container docker-test  Created                                                                                                                        0.0s 
Attaching to docker-test
```

I know that there is another solution to do that, by running the container in detached mode and then attach to this container by those commands `sudo docker compose up -d` and then `sudo docker attach <container_name>`.

But I wanna know, why the first way doesn't work.

Comment: what does this have to do with shell or linux?

Comment: I didn't know the attach workaround, thanks! I also wanna know why the first way doesn't work

Comment: @xpusostomos it involves the terminal so it has to do with shell and linux...

Comment: It probably doesn't work because the stdout of whatever is running in the container goes to the logs. And I'm not sure why you think running it would attach you to its stdin. docker exec -ti XXX /bin/bash is the usual way.